# how to resolve error in login page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new in PHP coding, I'm trying to make a login page but I got an error which I dont understand.

**login.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login_dash.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>User Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**login_dash.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
<?php
//var_dump($_POST);
// Grab User submitted information
$user = $_POST["myusername"];
$pass = $_POST["mypassword"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","jj");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("jj",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM login WHERE myusername = $user");
var_dump($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,$con);

if($row["myusername"]==$user && $row["mypassword"]==$pass)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I got following error which I couldint uderstand

**Error:**

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SRK\login_dash.php on line 27

Comment: Should be `SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM login WHERE myusername = '$user'` (_See the single quotes ?_)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't write new code using the `mysql_*` functions. They are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. Your code will stop working then. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instead.

Comment: Junaid, I strongly advise you to look for a different/newer tutorial, which is written with mysqli or PDO - just add those keywords to your search terms in google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because the query returns false so something is wrong.
Try

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM login WHERE myusername = '$user'");
```

And mysql functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5 you should use PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 1):

This is because your query failed to execute because the username is not enclosed within quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM login WHERE myusername = '$user'");
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, *Prepared Statements* of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off [`SQL Injection attacks !`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

In any case you must check

```
if (null != $rseult && 0 != count(result)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,$con);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to do it like this?

```
$query = "SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM login WHERE myusername = '$user' AND mypassword =  '$pass' ";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {

// your code here - basically LOGGED IN
}

else {
// NOT logged in
}
```

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: And another thing is, that i cant see encryption of pass in your code - you have to compare encrypted with encrypted.